# Selenium WebDriver analyze large collection of links quickly

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a web page with an extremely large amount of links (around 300) and I would like to collect information on these links.

**Here is my code:**

```
beginning_time = Time.now
#This gets a collection of links from the webpage
tmp = driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//a[string()]")
end_time = Time.now
puts "Execute links:#{(end_time - beginning_time)*1000} milliseconds for #{tmp.length} links"


before_loop = Time.now
#Here I iterate through the links
tmp.each do |link|
    #I am not interested in the links I can't see
    if(link.location.x < windowX and link.location.y < windowY)
        #I then insert the links into a NoSQL database, 
        #but for all purposes you could imagine this as just saving the data in a hash table.
        $elements.insert({
            "text" => link.text,
            "href" => link.attribute("href"),
            "type" => "text",
            "x" => link.location.x,
            "y" => link.location.y,
            "url" => url,
            "accessTime" => accessTime,
            "browserId" => browserId
        })
    end
end
after_loop = Time.now
puts "The loop took #{(after_loop - before_loop)*1000} milliseconds"
```

It currently take 20ms to get the link collection and around 4000ms (or 4 seconds) to retrieve the information for the links. When I separate the accessors from the NoSQL insert, I find that the NoSQL insert only takes 20ms and that the majority of time is spent with the accessors (who became much slower after being separated from the NoSQL insert, for reasons I don't understand), which makes me conclude that the accessors must be executing JavaScript.

My question is: **How do I collect these links and their information more quickly?**

The first solution that came to mind was to try running two drivers in parallel, but WebDrivers are not thread-safe, meaning that I would have to create a new instance of the WebDriver and navigate to the page. This raises the question, how to download the source of the page so that it can be loaded into another driver, which cannot be done in Selenium, thus must be performed on Chrome itself with desktop automation tools, adding a considerable amount of overhead.

Another alternative I heard of was to stop use ChromeDriver and to just use PhantomJS, but I need to display the page in visual browser.

Is there any other alternative that I haven't considered yet?

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative of `driver.execute_script(%{return document.links;})` ?

Comment: That's not really the slowest part of my code, but I'm still curious. Does an alternative exist and is it faster?

Comment: You can use the like that - `driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//a")` to collect all the links..

Comment: I am currently examining the alternative and will return when I have conclusive proof as to which one is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using Webdriver purely to execute Javascript rather than access the objects.

A couple of ideas to try IF you drop using javascript (Excuse the java but you get the idea);

```
 //We have restricted via xpath so will get less links back AND will not haveto check the text within loop
        List<WebElement> linksWithText = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[text() and not(text()='')]"));

        for (WebElement link : linksWithText) {

            //Store the location details rather than re-get each time
            Point location = link.getLocation();
            Integer x = location.getX();
            Integer y = location.getY();

            if (x < windowX && y < windowY) {
                ///Insert all info using webdriver commands;
            }
        }
```

I normally use remote grids so performace is a key concern in my tests, hence why I always try to restrict by CSS Selectors or XPath rather than get everything and loop

Comment: Thanks Robbie. I'll run some benchmarks and add them to your answer.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on you Xpath expression? Specifically, what does `not(not(text()))` accomplish? Could it just be replaced with `text()` since it's just a double negative?

Comment: Finally, as I mentioned in my original question, everything got a lot slower when I tried to extract them to temporary variables instead of calling them directly (as you suggest in your answer). Although, Ruby isn't your language of choice, can you think of any reason this might be?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just knocked it up quickly and tested it in Firepath.  I have removed the double NOT

Comment: So what this code is doing? If I understood,probably can also write a Ruby version..

Comment: I'm in a bit of a pickle. Your code did run on average 1 second faster than my old code, but this totally wasn't the answer I was expecting, so I'm hesitant to accept it. This is possibly because this question is too general. I can take your code and integrate it into my question and see what other answers show up. Or I can accept your answer and close the question. What do you think?

Comment: Just read your comment on getting page source; yes, you can get the page source, open a new web driver and then use JavaScript to inject the page source

Comment: I've asked a new question in regards to getting the page source, but I'll re-iterate it here. What you're suggesting would re-inject the HTML, but I would like to have the content be identical to the original page that I'm copying (the location of the elements in particular) which is dictated by the CSS and JavaScript, so I would need to extract and inject those as well.

Comment: After further testing, I noticed that your Xpath expression ignores links of the format `<a><span>Text</span></a>`, as Xpath doesn't see them as having any text and they are filtered out by `//a[text()]`. Also, `//a[not(text='')]` doesn't actually filter empty links of the format `<a></a>`.

Comment: It turns out the correct xpath expression is `//a[normalize-space()]`, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Your requirement was links with text in between, if you'd have said to include child elements as well, I'd have created a different xpath