# How to duplicate/fork/deep-clone a Selenium WebDriver object instance

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm having problems optimizing my code as I described in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630317/selenium-webdriver-analyze-large-collection-of-links-quickly). I'm starting to think that I just need to have two instances of my WebDriver running at the same time. Is there a way to duplicate/fork/deep-clone a Selenium WebDriver object? I've tried naively Marshalling and Unmarshalling, but this did not give the desired result.

A successful use case would be making a copy of one window that is currently at website and generating another window at the same website with the same JavaScript and CSS from the instant of that cloning without having to ask a server for the page again, but just reloading it locally. Afterwards, they could diverge.

Comment: Did you see this - [**`window_handles`**](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver.html#window_handles-instance_method) ? Let me know if it helpful for you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to use what you mentioned to accomplish my goal? I've heard to that before, but I've only seen it applied before in the context of working with multiple windows. http://elementalselenium.com/tips/4-work-with-multiple-windows

Comment: Yes. you are right! You can open multiple window with the same driver object. And when done you can switch to another next window,and when done,can close the windows respectively.. etc.. If you want I can write a code to demonstrate how it works..Let me know :)

Comment: Yes, I would like to see that code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just to demonstrate that,I wrote the below code :-

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets"

link_arr = driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//a")[2..4]
link_arr.map!{|e| e.attribute("href")}

link_arr.each do |link|
     driver.execute_script("window.open(\"#{link}\")") if link
end

p driver.window_handles.size # => 4
# the below will give you the title of each opened window
p driver.window_handles.map{|d| driver.switch_to.window(d);driver.title}
# => ["Cascading Style Sheets - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia", 
#"Wiki Loves Monuments India | The Wikipedia photo contest around Cultural Heritage", 
#"Wiki Loves Monuments India | The Wikipedia photo contest around Cultural Heritage", 
#"Cascading Style Sheets - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"]
```

This way you can go to any desired browser window,and complete your work and close the window also.

Comment: I understand now that my question was not specific enough, I should have mentioned that I was hoping to accomplish this without download the page again. I have now updated my question. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: *this without download the page again.* means ?

Comment: Without having to go through the process of getting the page from the remote server. It would just reload the HTML and CSS it has saved locally. Maybe that is another question? I'm starting to think I may have been to general with this one... What do you think?

Comment: It seems I couldn't help you. I should delete my answer too.